# What DNS servers are used when connected to wireless data?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internet, data-connection, dns

What DNS servers are used when connected to wireless data (not wifi)?

Is there a way within Android KitKat to tell?

Comment: Out of curiosity could you tell me why you're asking this? Is it to do with security/privacy concerns? Have you looked into DNSSEC/DNSCrypt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run "nslookup google.com" from Terminal Emulator and the first result should be your DNS. Also you could run a standard test from dnsleaktest.com from your browser.

Edit: I just noticed this answer is kind of outdated for newer Androids because nslookup doesn't seem to run if you install Terminal Emulator. The modern method seems to be to install Termux and then install dnsutils in Termix `pkg install dnsutils` and then run the same command `nslookup google.com`.

Comment: Does running the command involve downloading a Terminal Emulator from the Play Store, or is there one built-in to stock Android?  There are many apps in the Play Store claiming to be the real Terminal Emulator.  If a download is required, is one of those considered to be the standard?

Comment: There won't be many stock roms out there witb terminal emulators as standard, you will need to get one from Play. Get the one by Jack Palevich. Searching his name and terminal should  get you there.

Comment: Thank you!  Answer accepted!  Given the info provided by m.chinni below, I decided that the website you provided is probably the best answer.  Hopefully it is reliable.

Answer (score 6):

While the `setprop` method to change DNS does not work, the `getprop` method to read those values should be still valid today:

```
shell@A0001:/ $ getprop | grep dns
[dhcp.wlan0.dns1]: [192.168.1.1]
[dhcp.wlan0.dns2]: []
[dhcp.wlan0.dns3]: []
[dhcp.wlan0.dns4]: []
[net.change]: [net.rmnet0.dns2]
[net.dns1]: [208.67.222.123]
[net.dns2]: [208.67.220.123]
[net.rmnet0.dns1]: [208.67.222.123]
[net.rmnet0.dns2]: [208.67.220.123]
[net.wlan0.dns1]: [208.67.222.123]
[net.wlan0.dns2]: [208.67.220.123]
```

To clarify my answer: using a terminal emulator app (like [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)), as a normal user (no root permissions needed), you can execute the command I showed (`getprop | grep dns`) and get an output like that.

Comment: @mchinni Thanks. Can you enhance your answer to explain how and where to use that command?

Comment: This just  gives a list of DNS servers that are in the config, it doesn't  tell you with any certainty which is in  use. My method  works better here imo.

Comment: @warsong You are right, but starting from Android 4.2 if you type `nslookup google.com` the `Server` line will be like `Server:    0.0.0.0` because the name resolution is performed locally and forwarded to the DNS only if needed. With `getprop` (which is not future proof), today you receive the current DNS values.

Comment: @m.chinni Thank you.  I was thinking I was doing something wrong.  I gave your answer a +1 because it is also very useful.  For now, I hope the website warsong provided is the most reliable.

Comment: I agree. My commands show the configuration, but if your carrier perform some kind of DNS hijacking, with the site @warsong provided, you'll see the "real" DNS servers you are using. It's your choice the kind of information you need.